# 'Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client' error received after attempted to serve new html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, spotify

I'm very new to NodeJS, and I'm trying to follow/build off of a sample project built with the Spotify API and Express. The user is prompted to authenticate on the home page, and then I want to have them land at a different html file where relevant information will be displayed from the API. To my understanding "app.get" specifies what should happen once that endpoint is navigated to, so I thought that when my client.js file gets '/nextfile', I would present it with a new html file for that endpoint with `response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/nextpage.html');` within `app.get('/nextpage')`.

Obviously, this isn't correct, because when I run the server, it simply returns to the index.html file after authentication, with an error that reads:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

I tried looking into this error, but I couldn't find anything that helped me solve my specific problem. Relevant excerpts from my client.js and server.js files are below:

***Server.js***

```
    /**  when home page is requested, respond with this file **/
app.get("/", function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});


//-------------------------------------------------------------//


// init Spotify API wrapper
var SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');

// Replace with your redirect URI, required scopes, and show_dialog preference
var redirectUri = 'http://localhost:8888/callback',
    clID = '9013dc5d86b84ffca62df2f22e00968e',
    clSEC = 'b9484118ab374707925b1b15100cc58b';

var scopes = ['user-top-read','streaming','user-read-private'];
var showDialog = true;

// The API object we'll use to interact with the API
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId : clID,
  clientSecret : clSEC,
  redirectUri : redirectUri
});

app.get("/authorize", function (request, response) {
  var authorizeURL = spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scopes, null, showDialog);
  console.log(authorizeURL)
  response.send(authorizeURL);
});

// Exchange Authorization Code for an Access Token
app.get("/callback", function (request, response) {
  var authorizationCode = request.query.code;

  spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(authorizationCode)
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    response.redirect(`/#access_token=${data.body['access_token']}&refresh_token=${data.body['refresh_token']}`)
  }, function(err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong when retrieving the access token!', err.message);
  });
});

app.get("/logout", function (request, response) {
  response.redirect('/'); 
});

    app.get('/nextpage', function (request, response) {
      **/* I want to serve his html file after the user is authenticated */**
      response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/nextpage.html');

      var loggedInSpotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();
      console.log(request.headers['authorization'].split(' ')[1]);
      loggedInSpotifyApi.setAccessToken(request.headers['authorization'].split(' ')[1]);
      // do stuff with the api
    });
```

***Client.js***

```
$(function() {

    $('#login').click(function() {
      // Call the authorize endpoint, which will return an authorize URL, then redirect to that URL
      $.get('/authorize', function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        window.location = data;
      });
    });

    const hash = window.location.hash
      .substring(1)
      .split('&')
      .reduce(function (initial, item) {
        if (item) {
          var parts = item.split('=');
          initial[parts[0]] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
        }
        return initial;
      }, {});
      window.location.hash = '';

    if (hash.access_token) {
      $.get({url: '/nextpage', headers: {"Authorization": `Bearer ${hash.access_token}`}}, function(data) {
        // "Data" is the array of track objects we get from the API. See server.js for the function that returns it.
        console.log(data)

        var title = $('<h3>Your top tracks on Spotify:</h3>');
        title.prependTo('#data-container-mod');

        // For each of the tracks, create an element
        data.items.forEach(function(track) {
          var trackDiv = $('<li class="track"></li>');
          trackDiv.text(track.name);
          trackDiv.appendTo('#data-container ol');
        });

      });
    }

  });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Unhanded Promise Rejection is occurring because something is trying to set the response headers after you have resolved the HTTP request. My suggestion would be to use a debugger and insert some break points to see when the error occurs. Another thing: You mention that your `index.html` page is returned, yet that file is not mentioned anywhere in your code. Do you have any route/middleware that does return that file?

Comment: @abondoa Well, the error is caused by the line "response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/nextpage.html');" in my app.get("/nextpage") method. I've also updated my post to include the route to my index.html page.

Answer (score 0):

The flow of your app in sending http headers appears to be like this from when the 'callback' url is reached at:-

1. A http header is sent alongside the redirect URL that contains the access token and refresh token.
2. Client.js  takes the access token and sends it back through the /nextpage route with headers containing the access token
3. Send nextpage.html back to client.js and update the page accordingly..

What happens next?
Beware the browser  tab still is on the route with the access tokens and refresh tokens.
So the jquery ajax request to '/nextpage' runs while the previous http headers had been sent already.

I however do not understand how the index.html is being returned..

can you try removing the  window.location.hash=' ' in client.js

Comment: I tried moving that line as you suggested, but nothing changed, index.html still loads. And what are you suggesting causes the "headers already set error"? Because when I remove the line "response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/nextpage.html')" I don't get that error.

Comment: What is the route on the browser when the index.html is displayed/sent?

Comment: /#access_token=#######&refresh_token=########

Comment: If you do res.send('anything here')...is the error still being thrown?

Comment: Yep, the same exact thing.